# Unit test custom validator expected to be false but the test fails

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Testing a custom validator, I expect the validator to be false and yet the test continues to fail, the validator is supposed to check that if years in employment are greater than the birthdate then it should display an error message. I created two tests, one where I passed parameters that would make the validator to equal true triggering the error message to display, and another test where the parameters would not trigger the validator.
[image]

Test `.spec` file

```
    import {FormValidationService} from './form-validation.service';

fdescribe('FormValidationService', () => {
  
  let service: FormValidationService;
  const form: FormControl = new FormControl();
  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new FormValidationService();
  })
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('check the validation if years in employment is greater than years alive', () => 
   {
    
    const birthDate = new Date().setFullYear(1992, 6, 26).toString();
    const years = '40';
    const months = '0';
    
    const fn = service.dobLengthValidator(birthDate, years, months);
    const val = fn(form)
    expect(val).toBeTruthy()
    
  })
  it('check the validation if years in employment is less than years alive', () => {
    
    const birthDate = new Date().setFullYear(1992, 6, 26).toString();
    const years = '4';
    const months = '0';
    
    const fn2 = service.dobLengthValidator(birthDate, years, months);
    const val2 = fn2(form)
    expect(val2).toBeFalsy()
    
  })
   
});
```

Component `.ts` file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { CalculateStartDate } from '@app/utils';
import {environment} from '@environments/environment';
import { isBefore, isValid, subYears } from 'date-fns';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { Address } from '../models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormValidationService {


  dobLengthValidator = (dob: string, yrsFieldName: string, monthFieldName: string): ValidatorFn => {
    return (form: FormGroup) : ValidationErrors | null => {
      const yrs: string = !!yrsFieldName ? form.get(yrsFieldName)?.value ?? '0' : '0';
      const mths: string = !!monthFieldName ? form.get(monthFieldName)?.value ?? '0' : '0';
      const timeAliveTimestamp = new Date(dob).getTime();
      const timeEnteredTimestamp = new Date(CalculateStartDate(yrs, mths)).getTime();

      return timeAliveTimestamp >= timeEnteredTimestamp ? {dobLengthValidator: true} : null;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `dobLengthValidator` returns a function, so it will always be truthy.

If you want to test that function, you need to call its returned function and pass it a `FormGroup` object:

```
const fn2 = service.dobLengthValidator(birthDate, years, months);
const val2 = fn2(someForm);
expect(val2).toBeFalsy();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am new to angular, so not quite sure how to pass the FormGroup, I have added this to the top of the describe 'const form: FormControl = new FormControl();' and passed form as a parameter but it not accessing the form object...'const val = fn(form)'

Comment: if you pass a new FormControl, it will not have the expected properties (`yrsFieldName` and `monthFieldName`). You need to add them to the FormControl and then pass it to the function